# convert json with nested dicts into data frame with python

Tags: python, json

can someone explain how I convert the following json into a simple data frame with the following headings?

----- sample----

```
{
    "last_scanned_block": 14968718,
    "blocks": {
        "13965799": {
            "0x9603846aff5c425277e483de16179a68dbc739debcc5449ea99e45c9d0924430": {
                "165": {
                    "from": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                    "to": "0x01f87c337be5636Cd9B3D48F1159768A7e7837A5",
                    "value": 100000000000000000000000000,
                    "timestamp": "2022-01-08T16:19:02"
                }
            }
        },
        "13965820": {
            "0xd4a4122734a522c40504c8b0ab43b9aa40ac821cd9913179b3ae64e5b166fc57": {
                "226": {
                    "from": "0x01f87c337be5636Cd9B3D48F1159768A7e7837A5",
                    "to": "0xEa3Fa123Eb40CEEaeED390D8d6dE6AF95f044AF7",
                    "value": 610000000000000000000000,
                    "timestamp": "2022-01-08T16:25:12"
                }
            }
        },
```

--- end----

I'd like the df to have the following 8 column headings and values for each row

(value examples for first row)

- Last_scanned_block: 14968718
- block: 13965799
- hex: 0x9603846aff5c425277e483de16179a68dbc739debcc5449ea99e45c9d0924430
- number: 165
- from: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000
- to: 0x01f87c337be5636Cd9B3D48F1159768A7e7837A5
- value: 100000000000000000000000000
- timestamp: 2022-01-08T16:19:02

Thanks

Comment: Share what code you have tried so far to solve the problem. You are basically asking someone to write the code for you which is not the purpose here. Instead, if you have tried some code and faced issues, you should include that and get help.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a new dictionary from the json that is passed in. Essentially instead of having nested dictionaries like you have above you want to get them into one simple dictionary according to your headings and values. It should be:

```
*heading name* : *list of values*
```

Essentially, the resulting format should be:

```
{"Last_scanned_block" : [14968718], "block" : [13965799], "hex" : ["0x9603846aff5c425277e483de16179a68dbc739debcc5449ea99e45c9d0924430"], "number" : [165], "from" : ["0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"], "to" : ["0x01f87c337be5636Cd9B3D48F1159768A7e7837A5"], "value": [100000000000000000000000000], "timestamp" : ["2022-01-08T16:19:02"]}
```

Then every time you read more data you just append it to each respective list in your dictionary.

Once you have your complete dictionary, you would use pandas. So something along the lines of:

```
import pandas
d = *the dictionary above*
frame = pandas.DataFrame(data = d)
print(frame)
```

Comment: So I created this code so far: